# How do you make a comment in Pep8

Tags: pep8-assembly

How do I add a comment to my Pep8 code?

Answer (score 2):

Use a semi-colon(;)

```
;This is a comment
```

The comment should turn green.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comment to the code using # symbol.Comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement. They should start with a # and a single space. Multi-line comments can be done using """Triple-Quotes"""
eg: x=x+1   # Increment x by 1

Comment: This is for Python, not PEP/8 assembly.